How to do sleep/delay system call in MacOS Apple Silicon
I am learning arm64 assembly for MacOS Apple Silicon and wanted to write a console game. For this I wanted to generate some FPS kind of thing like, waiting 1/10th of a second and rendering a frame to generate 10 FPS.
I did this in c++ using usleep from unistd.h, and want recreate this in Assembly, I am going through the open source xnu system calls page from this link.
I did see wait4 and I don't know what values to pass as arguments.
I tried the solution from this m1 mac, calling nanosleep from assembly
.global _main
_main:
    mov x8, 3
    mov x8, xzr, [sp, -0x10]! // 3 seconds
    mov x0, sp
    mov x1, 0
    bl _nanosleep
    add sp, sp, 0x10

But got error as below
main.asm:4:15: error: invalid operand for instruction
        mov x8, xzr, [sp, -0x10]! // 3 seconds

Please help, Thanks.

This question might be of interest: m1 mac, calling nanosleep from assembly.

@fuz Tried the solution but my default macOS assembler(as) is throwing invalid operand error.

Are you programming for amd64 by chance?  The linked question concerns arm64 macs, for which the assembly language is different.  However, the same system calls should be needed on amd64, too.

No, I am using MacBook Air M1 which uses arm64

Could you [edit] your question to show the code you tried and error message you got?  Maybe I can help you with that.

Edited the question. Please help if I made any mistakes. I am new to this and want to learn as much as possible.

Check the source you copied from.  You wrote mov when the instruction should have been stp.

Sorry for that, edited the question.

Thank you so much, I was careless, that fixed the issue. Can you point me to some sources so that I can learn more.

Kind of hard to say.  I recommend having a copy of the ARM Architecture Reference Manual on how the various instructions work.

I tried this earlier, but in the official site there are multiple things like A-Profile, M-Profile etc. Which one should I look at?  https://www.arm.com/architecture/learn-the-architecture

You need document DDI0487 “ARM Architecture Reference Manual for A-Profile Architecture.”
